# What is the java.nio.file equivalent of File.createNewFIle()

Tags: java, file, io, nio, atomic

What is the equivalent of [`File.createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) in [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) API (Java 7+)?

Comment: I would guess [`Files.createFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you've got the `Files` class which got a method called `createFile`

```
Files.createFile(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute<T>...)
```

The `FileAttribute<T>` parameter is optional so you don't need to put something in for that.

To get a `Path` there is a `Paths` class to get a path easily.

```
java.nio.file.Path get(java.lang.String path, java.lang.String... more)
```

Answer (score 0):

All actual file operations are [in the `Files` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)):

```
Files.createFile(path);
```